# Need help in finding a excel formula for entering values if it's in the date period

Tags: excel, wsp

[image]

I'm trying to find a `If` and `AND` formula to use for entering values under the date columns to return me those values.

It should only show values under the date according to the PSD and PFD (Product Start Date and Product Finish Date). I have been trying to search all over internet for this but couldn't so it would be helpful if this community could help me out with this.

Let me know if you would like more information.

I was trying different `IF` and `AND` formulas but I couldn't make it show only under columns with the specific date on them. I want the rest to be blank like shown in the picture.

Comment: if(and(date > X, date < Y),do this, do that)

Comment: ^^^ Assumes that the "dates" are true dates and not text that look like dates, and that they all are the same year, or that you only have the one month.  If they are text and have multiple months, then getting this to work will be very difficult.

Comment: `=IF(AND($L2>=$F5<=$G5),I5,"")` I tried this but it returned as Blank

Comment: Try: `=IF(AND(L$2>=$F5,L$2<=$G5),$I5,"")`

Comment: I put and(date > X, date < Y) so date was compared to X and Y in separate arguments, if both are true then if() returns "do this". You did something different in the and().